# Tengo el problema de que al implementar un dialog a un boton no para de ejecutarse sin que se cumpla la condicion (android studio)

Tags: java, android

```
public class CuadroDialogo{
    

    public interface FinalizoCuadroDialogo
    {
        void ResultadoCuadroDialogo(String valor);
    }


    private FinalizoCuadroDialogo interfaz;

    public CuadroDialogo(Context contexto, FinalizoCuadroDialogo actividad){

        interfaz = actividad;

        final Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(contexto);
        dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.cuadro_dialogo);
        
        TextView aceptar = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.vamos);
        //TextView rechazar = (TextView) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.textViewsI2);

        aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dialogo.dismiss();

            }
        });

        dialogo.show();

    }
}
```

En ese tableLayout se introducen palabras y cuando es incorrecta aparece un cuadro de dialogo, el tema es que yo quero que el cuadro salga solo cuando la condicion sea ciert. Al primer toque funciona prefectamente la idea pero despues ignora la condicion y se ejecuta siempre cuando presiono el boton.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde realizas la validacion para saber si la condicion es cierta?

Comment: hola, la validacion la hago en la clase principal simplemente valido si "contador" es igual a 5 y si es igual a cinco llamo al evento, osea al dialog. Y sí, así pasa se ejecuta correctamente, pero el problema es que cuando aparece otra palabra. Te explico yo estoy haciendo un juego de adivinar palabras, tienes 5 intentos, si llegas a cinco intentos te aprece un cuadro de dialogo avisandote que perdiste. Porque si la primera vez que se llama al cuadro de dialogo todo funciona pero las siguientes veses ignora la condición completamente, se ejecuta siempre(al presionar el boton) osea la letra.